# addautomtioneventhandler on web pages

Tags: event-handling, ui-automation

I'm trying to add an automation event handler for a ui button. I've tested on desktop applications and it's working but I've a problem with buttons in web pages.In fact I can invoke them with InvokePattern.Invoke() but I don't see the handler working after that!

this is my code :

```
if ((wantedElement != null))
                    {
                        element = wantedElement;
                        buttonEvent = new AutomationEventHandler(close_event);
                      Automation.AddAutomationEventHandler(InvokePattern.InvokedEvent, element,TreeScope.Element,buttonEvent );

                        object pattern;
                        if (wantedElement.TryGetCurrentPattern(InvokePattern.Pattern, out pattern))
                        {

                            InvokePattern invokePattern = (InvokePattern)pattern;
                            invokePattern.Invoke();                                
                        }                            
                    }
```

...

```
private static void close_event(object sender, AutomationEventArgs e)
    {
        AutomationElement sourceElement;
        try
        {
            sourceElement = sender as AutomationElement;
            Console.WriteLine("button try");
        }
        catch (ElementNotAvailableException)
        {
            return;
        }
        if (e.EventId == InvokePattern.InvokedEvent)
        {
            // TODO Add handling code.
            Console.WriteLine("button invoked");
        }
        else
        {
            // TODO Handle any other events that have been subscribed to.
            Console.WriteLine("button event");                
        }

    }
```

Comment: What browser are you using?  Automation support is dependent on the browser.  IE 9 & below have fairly limited automation support; IE 10 & above have much better support.

Comment: What about firefox ??

Comment: I'm not that familiar with firefox, but a web search yields [this link](http://asurkov.blogspot.com/2012/06/uia-implementation-in-firefox.html) which suggests that recent versions of firefox should have UI Automation support.

Comment: I upgraded IE to version 10 but nothing changes!

Comment: Can you add the relevant portion of your web page?  Are you using <button> elements, or are you using elements with onclick handlers?  If the latter, you'll need to add [ARIA](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Accessibility/ARIA?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=ARIA) annotations to your document so that Mozilla and IE can actually *find* your buttons.

Comment: I'm using button elements! in fact i also tried with facebook connexion button and gmail connexion button, i'm able to invoke them but i never see my event working!

Comment: One other thing I noticed is that you are mixing native UIA from Internet Explorer with managed UIA in your app.  I'm following up with some friends, but you might be having some interop issues.  You might try the [UIA COM Wrapper](http://uiacomwrapper.codeplex.com/) and see if it helps.

Comment: Sorry, i had the chance to review the problem only these days, thank you so much for your help i tried the wrapper and it worked, i still have some exceptions to deal with. One more thing is that for one click the handler is triggered too many times so i have to deal with that also.